# Chaining + zipping multiple network requests using Swift and Combine

Tags: swift, combine

Overall use case is 4 network requests

- A. Request 1 and 2 need to be in parallel and wait for both to
  complete
- B. Request 3 happens after 1 and 2 complete
- C. Request 4
  happens after 3 completes

After C the final output should be of a `AnyPublisher` type

I am trying to use Combine to achieve the above and so far I am able to do A using `Publishers.Zip` and C using `flatMap`. What I am struggling with is B. I can do that using nested completion handlers but not using `flatMap`

This is the sample code with Strings (not actual code)

```
func overallFunc(arg1: "arg1", arg2: "arg2", arg3: "arg3", arg4: "arg4" ) -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error> {
let pub1 = func1(arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2)
let pub2 = func2(arg1: arg3, arg2: arg4)

let combinedPub = Publishers.Zip(pub1, pub2)

combinedPub
   .flatMap {(response1, response2) in
     return func3(arg1: response1.attribute1, arg2: response2.attribute2)
   }
}
```

The `func1`, `func2` and `func3` all return `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher` with return type say  `AnyPublisher<String?, Error>`

Now I am struggling with completing the code for `overallFunc`. The complier gives the following error around `flatMap`.

`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

If I add an extra return in the last line of `overallFunc` then the error changes to
`No 'flatMap' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'AnyPublisher<String?, Error>'`

In short I want to use `flatMap` on the result of `Publishers.Zip` and return another publisher so that I can add another `flatMap` to do the 4th request but am not able to figure out the right syntax and order of things to do that.

Comment: Try explicitly adding the types for the `flatMap` closure arguments and return type, the compiler should give you a better error message.

Comment: I am quite certain you have a return type mismatch. However, it would help to see the method signatures for all of your methods (ie: func1/2/3). You should post a complete example. I'm also confused as to what you plan on returning from overallFunc. combinedPub? combinedPub.eraseToAnyPublisher()? etc.

Comment: @Cristik Thanks! Adding the return type helped and gave more helpful error messages.

Comment: @Cristik If you provide your comment as an answer I can accept it as the solution.

Comment: I only suggested a debugging technique, and I feel this doesn't qualify for an answer. You should  add an answer instead, with the code changes you made, and perhaps mention in the answer that a comment helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your attempt to obfuscate the code has removed the problem you were having. The following code compiles just fine:

```
func func1(arg1: String, arg2: String) -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error> { fatalError() }
func func2(arg1: String, arg2: String) -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error> { fatalError() }
func func3(arg1: String, arg2: String) -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error> { fatalError() }
func func4(arg1: String) -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error> { fatalError() }

func overallFunc(arg1: String, arg2: String, arg3: String, arg4: String) -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error> {
    Publishers.Zip(
        func1(arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2),
        func2(arg1: arg3, arg2: arg4)
    )
        .flatMap { (response1, response2) in
            func3(arg1: response1 ?? "", arg2: response2 ?? "")
        }
        .flatMap { response3 in
            func4(arg1: response3 ?? "")
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Sorry will provide a more concrete example next time. Thank you for the answer! Adding `.eraseToAnyPublisher` helped in isolating the problem a bit better. What solved it was adding the return type explicitly within the `flatMap` closure.

Comment: Ah yes. If you have more than one line of code in the flatMap, then you usually have to define the return type (unless there is something outside the closure that make it clear to the compiler what the return type is supposed to be.)

Answer (score 1):

The result of `flatMap` is going to be a `String?` (the result of request 3) that you then want to pass to `map`.  That `map` will convert the String into the fourth request.  You could then add a subscriber to the fourth request which will be the result of your overall sequence.  So...

```
pub1
  .zip(pub2)
  .flatMap { (response1, response2) in
     func3(arg1: response1.attribute1, arg2: response2.attribute2)
  }
  .map {
     (func3Result : String?) in
      /* return publisher of 4th request */
  }
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

The result of all of this will be the publisher of the 4th request.