# Swift Combine chain 2 network request synced

Tags: ios, swift, combine

so i am kinda new to Combine and i am trying to do 2 network requests one after another.

```
func fetchData2() {
    
    loading = true
    print(" fetchData")
    
    _ = userService.getToken()
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .map { $0 }
        .compactMap { self.userService.getBand(token: $0.access_token) }
        .map { $0 }
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.loading = false
        },receiveValue: { [weak self] result in
            self?.loading = false
            print(result)
        })
}

protocol UserServiceProtocol {
func getToken() -> AnyPublisher<TokenModel, Error>
func getBand(token: String)  -> AnyPublisher<BandModel, Error>
}
```

These are the models:

```
struct TokenModel: Codable {
var access_token: String
var token_type: String
var expires_in: Int
}

struct BandModel: Codable {
var external_urls: External
var followers: Follower
var genres: [String]
var href: String
var id: String
var images: [ImageCode]
var name: String
var popularity: Int
var type: String
var uri: String
}
```

The result gives me : <PublisherBox<Decode<TryMap<SubscribeOn<DataTaskPublisher, OS_dispatch_queue>, Data>, BandModel, JSONDecoder>>: 0x600002911ce0>

and i am expecting BandModel.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the missing part was adding:  `private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()` and then add this to the end of the chain `.store(in: &cancellables)`

```
 _ = userService.getToken()
        .flatMap { self.userService.getBand(token: $0.access_token) }
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.loading = false
        },receiveValue: { [weak self] result in
            self?.loading = false
            print(result)
        }).store(in: &cancellables)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `flatMap` instead of last `map` - u need to *unwrap* the `publisher` and execute it, instead, u just create a `publisher` that consist from 2 task

also, are u sure about

```
.receive(on: RunLoop.main)
```

read more about `RunLoop.main scheduler` [here](https://khorbushko.github.io/article/2020/12/01/schedulers-in-combine-runLoop.html)

---

instead of this:

```
_ = userService.getToken()
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .map { $0 }
    .compactMap { self.userService.getBand(token: $0.access_token) }
    .map { $0 }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.loading = false
    },receiveValue: { [weak self] result in
        self?.loading = false
        print(result)
    })
```

try to do

```
_ = userService.getToken()
    // check this scheduler
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    // not sure if u need this... if u don't extract anything, probably u want
    // .map { $0.access_token }
    .map { $0 }
    // .flatMap { self.userService.getBand(token: $0) } instead of .compactMap...
    .compactMap { self.userService.getBand(token: $0.access_token) }
    // flatMap - here is the type u want as $0
    .map { $0 }
    // advice - check result - it might be [failed][2] 
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.loading = false
    },receiveValue: { [weak self] result in
        self?.loading = false
        print(result)
    })
```

[similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69684714/22678415) to u'r I believe

Comment: Tried it, yet not unwrapping it

Answer (score 0):

You need to store cancellation handler somewhere where it can outlive requests. I think what you really want to do is this:

```
class Controller {
    private var cancellers = [AnyCancellable]()
    
    func fetchData2() {
        loading = true
        print(" fetchData")
        
        userService.getToken()
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .flatMap { self.userService.getBand(token: $0.access_token) }
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in
                self?.loading = false
            },receiveValue: { [weak self] result in
                self?.loading = false
                print(result)
            })
            .store(in: &cancellers)
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that... not working.
userService.getBand still wraped

Comment: Can you send me getBand function signature?

Comment: @ Serge Vysotsky
  func getBand(token: String)  -> AnyPublisher<BandModel, Error>

Comment: Then the result must be BandModel, just the type is wrapped and that is fine. If you don’t like that type is wrapped you can add .eraseToAnyPyblisher() just before .sink but it is fine if the type is different. It’s how combine works. Every call to method like .map wraps previous publisher into another publisher so if you had Published.Publisher<Int> and call map on it, the type becomes MapPublisher<Published.Publisher<Int>> and the output type becomes MapPublisher<Published.Publisher<Int>>.Output and not just Int, though it is Int actually

Comment: But i can see the result is not BandModel so how do i unwrap it ?

Comment: Just use it anywhere BandModel is needed. Can’t you access its properties on a result variable? Can you try and replace print with print(result.name) ? What output or error do you have? Thanks

Comment: result is type AnyPublisher<BandModel, Error>

Comment: That’s because you need to use flatMap

Comment: flatMap not invoking the request

Comment: That’s because you need to store the result of sink method somewhere. You can create var cancellers = [AnyCancellable]() on your controller and call store(in method after sink

Comment: I have updated the answer with more detail